# Где можно найти Java / Android проекты для новичков?

Tags: java, android

У меня не очень обширные знания в программировании: обычно создавал программы типа баз данных, например "Студенты" (кто и когда опоздал, и тому подобное). Также создавал телефонную книжку и прогноз погоды на Android.

Собственно последнее мне очень понравилось. Udacity предоставляет курс, где поэтапно рассказано, как создать программу. Аналогов я больше не находил (чтобы какой-то большой и интересный проект так классно объясняли). Но очень хотелось бы! Ну или хотя бы идеи, что создать новичку. Вот сейчас подсказали счётчик коммунальных услуг; также в интернете нашел этот [список](http://www.lovelycoding.org/2014/04/Java-Project-Ideas-United-State.html)

Много информации, а не знаешь, за что взяться. Мне сказали: меньше читай — больше пиши, и уже по мере написания кода будешь изучать интересующие тебя аспекты.

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ годные туториалы

Comment: Могу посоветовать «Android. Программирование для профессионалов» (авторы Брайн Харди, Билл Филлипс). Информация, описанная во втором издании данной книги вполне актуальна. Несмотря на название, в книге идет объяснение с нуля (но `java` знать нужно).

Comment: На [github огромное количество проектов](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=android+app&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=✓) любых уровней сложности. Более детальный поиск поможет найти что то более конкретное

Comment: + к @s8am советую 2 издание все таки больше, так как там рассматриваются более актуальные вещи

Answer (score 7):

Рекомендую тебе [Android 6 для профессионалов 2015](https://vk.com/doc273848965_437760512?hash=de3600d414e26ba6ca&dl=c1e300feeec5826991)

Актуальная книга на **русском языке** с упором на практику со множеством интересных проектов в коробке, в ходе рассмотрения которых автор затрагивает большинство аспектов фреймфорка, дающие достаточно знаний для **старта** кодинга на Android. 

Ну а после книги развивай умения и знания в ходе поиска решений для конкретных задач, чтением литературы и в процессе общения с хорошими людьми.

***PS*** (Не смотря на то, что в русском варианте книга называется для **"... профессионалов"**, книга читается легко и после прочтения глав не остается неясностей, так автор тщательно разжевывает понятия и неявные участки кода)

Где-то еще скачивал исходники проектов книги, но, к сожалению, ссылку не смог найти вновь.

Ну, а если же тебе интересны видеоуроки, то в России самый крупнейший - это безусловно [StartAndroid](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzE7HcbvyEiS5ea1rVRbPLQ). 

Так же тоже следует обратить внимание на http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/ (P.S *наимилейший сайт в рунете*)